Error when trying to login through a Webdriver (Python Selenium)
I'm trying to do some scraping on hellofresh.fr using Python Selenium, but I'm failing on the 1st step, logging in.
When clicking on the submit button, an error message appears in the browser (rough translation of the error message: oops! an error occured. please try again, and if the problem is still there, contact our customer service).
Error message shown in the browser
I tried reducing the automated actions to a minimum, so now I'm just opening the login page on a webdriver, and doing everything (filling the password, clicking the submit button) by hand, so my code is just:
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.hellofresh.fr/login")

It's still giving me the error message.
I tried using other browsers (chrome and edge), no difference.
Obviously, the problem doesn't occur when doing the same actions outside of the webdriver, in a normal browser.
Is this some kind of protection against scraping, and if so, how can I avoid it?

Selenium is easily flagged by browser.
Plenty methods to try to hide Selenium from browser exist (also to flag Selenium) exist and are already listed on internet.
Some of them work. It depend of the protection website against bot activity.
To test if you browser is flagged, see here.
To begin your search about what browser data are collecting and how you're flagged on internet look at fingerprint and cookies.
Some method to stealth selenium activity (source : selenium-avoid-bot-detection) :

Disabling the Automation Indicator WebDriver Flags
Rotating HTTP Header Information and User-Agent
Remove JavaScript Signature

Also, you can see package like undetected-chromedriver
Other way than Selenium exist to scrape data with Python using requests and beautifulsoup4.
RPA Platform like UiPath can be good too.
